# Undefined references to openssl symbols despite using -llibssl -llibcrypto

Tags: c

I need to make a function that turns the input text into a hashcode, but when I use OpenSSL functions I get "undefined reference to smth", where "smth" is a library function that OpenSSL should be providing. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

void sha3_256_hash(const char *input, unsigned char *output) {
    EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx;
    const EVP_MD *md;
    unsigned int md_len;

    md = EVP_sha3_256();

    mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();

    EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, md, NULL);

    EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, input, strlen(input));

    EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, output, &md_len);

    EVP_MD_CTX_free(mdctx);
}

int main() {
    const char *password = "Hello_World";
    unsigned char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    sha3_256_hash(password, hash);

    printf("SHA-3-256 Hash: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        printf("%02x", hash[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
**** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Test ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc "-IC:\\vcpkg\\packages\\openssl_x64-windows\\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\Test.o" "..\\src\\Test.c" 
gcc "-LC:\\vcpkg\\packages\\openssl_x64-windows\\lib" -o Test.exe "src\\Test.o" -llibssl -llibcrypto 
src\Test.o: In function `sha3_256_hash':
C:\Users\null_object\Documents\c_workspace\Test\Debug/../src/Test.c:12: undefined reference to `EVP_sha3_256'
C:\Users\null_object\Documents\c_workspace\Test\Debug/../src/Test.c:14: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_new'
C:\Users\null_object\Documents\c_workspace\Test\Debug/../src/Test.c:16: undefined reference to `EVP_DigestInit_ex'
C:\Users\null_object\Documents\c_workspace\Test\Debug/../src/Test.c:18: undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
C:\Users\null_object\Documents\c_workspace\Test\Debug/../src/Test.c:20: undefined reference to `EVP_DigestFinal_ex'
C:\Users\null_object\Documents\c_workspace\Test\Debug/../src/Test.c:22: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_free'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build Failed. 6 errors, 0 warnings. (took 446ms)
```

What should i do to fix this problem?

I've tried to google and fix this problem by myself but i couldnt(

Comment: `-lssl -lcrypto` is correct according to `pkg-config --cflags --libs openssl`

Comment: @RetiredNinja, the diagnostics show the undefined references being traced back to the OP's source file.  That's not going to be an issue with the relative order of two libraries, and it doesn't appear to be an issue with the order of the object file with respect to either library.

Comment: @RetiredNinja No, that's a correct observation. @qexlq: Drop `lib`.

Comment: Did you configure your vcpkg to build packages with MinGW as opposed to MSVC? If I were you, I'd rather use [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075), since MinGW is its primary focus.

Answer (score 0):

"lib" is assumed when you use a `-l` argument. It should be `-lssl -lcrypto`, not `-llibssl -llibcrypto`.

Comment: If the question is properly reflecting what's going on OP's side, there is a failure to link _after_ the libraries have been found.  A failure to find a listed libraries would likely manifest itself earlier. I'm not 100% sure, but that was my reason for not putting up an answer just like yours.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, indeed; if I strongly stood behind this it wouldn't have the "community wiki" flag set. Conceivable, I suppose, that we might be finding an older library version and newer headers; but the question doesn't provide enough details on how the components are installed to run that down should it be true.

Comment: Ah... finding an older lib would indeed be an interesting twist.

Comment: Yes, I know it, but when i use  -lssl -lcrypto i get:
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lssl
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcrypto

Comment: @gexlq, ...hm. `vcpkg`, unless I'm remembering incorrectly, implies things compiled with/for microsoft's Visual C++. Make sure you're linking against libraries that were themselves built with mingw32.